# opt to verb"ing" or opt to verb

Tags: verbs

can you please help if I need +"ing" after "opt to" 
My sentence is as below:

> User can also opt to not providing shear reinforcement

was that correct? or the below is correct

> User can also opt to not provide shear reinforcement

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 is incorrect.

Option 2 is correct.  This example uses a "split infinitive", which I think is OK.  (Some people disagree with me about that.)  The example would be even better with an article (or other determiner) before "user".  For example:

> A user can also opt to not provide shear reinforcement

or

> The user can also opt to not provide shear reinforcement

The "to <verb>" phrase is English's version of an infinitive.  It is often used after a helper verb, like "opt".

It is unusual to have "to <verb>ing" in a sentence.  One such situation is when the word "to" is used link gerunds.  For example, "I wanted to speed up, so I switched from walking to running."

Answer (score 1):

The correct form is : "User can also **opt not to** *provide* shear reinforcement".

Opt not to is the correct form, by the way as expressed in the other answer, you don't have to use ing-form of the verb here.